# netdata: view other servers from one dashboard

Tags: netdata

I've just installed `netdata` for testing as a replacement (or augment) for `nagios`.  I have it installed on one machine and it's great.

However, I'm trying to install `netdata` on a second machine ("cougar"), with the intent of using the first machine ("rolls-royce") as my sole dashboard/viewing host.

I believe I have followed the directions correctly from https://docs.netdata.cloud/streaming/ for setting up a "headless collector", where "cougar" is my "slave" instance and "rolls-royce" is my "master" instance.

**Update**: I also figured out that I need to have my own "registry"

cougar netdata.conf

```
 [global]
     memory mode = none

 [web]
     mode = none

[registry]
    # enabled = no
    registry to announce = http://rolls-royce:19999
```

cougar stream.conf

```
[stream]
    enabled = yes
    destination = rolls-royce:19999
    api key = 9447dae1-0830-4edd-9e70-1cd125844b65
    timeout seconds = 60
    default port = 19999
```

rolls-royce netdata.conf

```
[registry]
    enabled = yes
    registry to announce = http://rolls-royce:19999
```

rolls-royce stream.conf

```
[stream]
    enabled = no


[9447dae1-0830-4edd-9e70-1cd125844b65]
    enabled = yes
    allow from = *
    default history = 3600
    default memory mode = save
    health enabled by default = auto
    multiple connections = allow
```

And I think I see data being collected in the logs, and cache files being created.

However, I cannot figure out how to view my "cougar" data from my "rolls-royce" dashboard.

The documentation refers to a "my-netdata" menu.  I don't have a "my-netdata" menu.  I have a menu entitled "rolls-royce", with only a single entry for "rolls-royce  http://rolls-royce:19999/"  but no entry for "cougar".

Can anybody help me figure out what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

although it has been almost a year from the question, and you may accomplished this, take a look to the [github discussion](https://github.com/netdata/netdata/issues/3720#issuecomment-396085290) where the creator of netdata wrote a small script for that purpose. Here you go the script:

```
bash <(curl -Ss https://my-netdata.io/kickstart.sh) --dont-wait --dont-start-it

cat >/etc/netdata/netdata.conf <<EOF
[global]
  memory mode = none
[web]
  mode = none
EOF

cat >/etc/netdata/stream.conf <<EOF
[stream]
  enabled = yes
  destination = master-netdata
  api key = API KEY
EOF

systemctl start netdata
```

Comment: This is for slaves.  The question is for master.